# WIFI connected but not working in Lubuntu

Tags: wifi, lubuntu

I'm new to Linux in general and I have had difficulty with some wifi connections. Some work and some don't. When I look under edit connections everything looks the same and I am left rather puzzled as to what makes some of them work and some not.

Again, I'm new to Linux and am at a loss concerning what to try. After doing some googling it seemed like people who asked similar questions were asked to show the output from ifconfig and iwconfig. Mine is below.

```
forest@forest-Latitude-D600:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:"CenturyLink0032"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: B2:B2:DC:5A:44:EC   
          Bit Rate=48 Mb/s   Tx-Power=27 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=60/70  Signal level=-50 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:3  Invalid misc:82   Missed beacon:0

forest@forest-Latitude-D600:~$ ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:1996 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1996 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:131101 (131.1 KB)  TX bytes:131101 (131.1 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:90:4b:6b:a6:75  
          inet addr:192.168.0.158  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::290:4bff:fe6b:a675/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:592 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1334 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:136572 (136.5 KB)  TX bytes:152309 (152.3 KB)

forest@forest-Latitude-D600:~$
```

Pinging the address of the router seems to work fine. If I'm in a browser (Chrome) it just says "resolving host...". And suggestions would be appreciated! Thanks

*EDIT*

Based on requests. 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.158 both fail to load, however it spends longer trying to load the former than the latter.

Running less /etc/network/interfaces yielded

```
auto lo iface 
lo inet loopback 
/etc/network/interfaces (END)
```

*EDIT 2*
So it does work when I boot into windows. The output from ipconfig in windows gives

Windows IP Configuration

```
    Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : D600-105798

    Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : 

    Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid

    IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

    WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

    DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : PK5001Z
```

Ethernet adapter Wireless Network Connection 3:

```
    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : PK5001Z

    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Dell TrueMobile 1300 WLAN Mini-PCI Card

    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-90-4B-6B-A6-75

    Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes

    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

    IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.158

    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0

    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1

    DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1

    DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1

                                        205.171.2.25

    Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, December 23, 2014 8:14:35 AM

    Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, December 24, 2014 8:14:35 AM
```

Comment: Have you tried logging into your router?

Comment: @eyoung100 Yeah, it wasn't happy with that either...? i.e. it was the same result as trying to load a webpage

Comment: You have no eth0 either. What is does  `less /etc/network/interfaces` output?

Comment: Type http://192.168.0.1 in a browser.  Tell me what you get...

Comment: 192.168.0.1 Doesn't load either but it tries to for a while. Originally I did 192.168.0.158 and it quickly says it can't load but the other takes a while.

Comment: For less /etc/network/interfaces the output was  auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

/etc/network/interfaces (END)

Comment: Have you tried resetting your router?  If you can't reach your default gateway(192.168.0.1), you've got a bigger issue.  We need you logged in to the gateway to see if you have a WAN IP.

Comment: @eyoung100 I have dual boot and in windows the internet is working no problem. Does that change anything?

Comment: Yes, please open a Commaand Prompt as an admin, then type `ipconfig /all > C:\output.txt` and post `output.txt`.